# Загрузка с CD выдаёт - CD BOOT ERROR 0x73

Tags: boot

Доброго дня всем.
**CD BOOT ERROR 0x73**  при загрузке с Boot-CD... В просторах инета нарыл два туманных ответа про BIOS и про Мамкин чип.
Соль в том, что BIOS'у не нравятся boot-сектора дисков?
Выход - перепрошивака BIOS или упорные поиски по знакомым, или по рунету "правильного" образа с "правильными" boot-секторами?

P.S. *Второй раз уже встречаю такие мамки за 12 лет! Разрабам бы эти же мамки!*

Comment: еслиб название мамки еще было, то может чтото конкретнее сказать можно было бы)

Answer (score 2):

Скорее что привод как то криво обрабатывает `boot` сектор диска. Можно попробовать перешить биос, небольшой шанс, что поможет. Можно попробовать для проверки другой привод, на котором этот диск нормально грузится на другом ПК. Еще очень может быть, что поможет подключение usb привода.

Answer (score 0):

`Plop или Plop Boot Manager` - это универсальный загрузчик. Он может загружать операционные системы с жестких дисков, флопидисков, CD/DVD и USB. Особенно полезно для тех, кто не может грузиться с USB.

Answer (score 0):

А BIOS - UEFI? Если там есть такая возможность - отключите!

Comment: Bios не UEFI, хотя как почитал проблема в самом биосе.  (неправильная реакция на некоторые загрузчики)